# authorization error while setup ssh into elastic beanstalk intance

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

i am trying to install ssh on my elastic beanstalk instance via eb console.
I get the following authorization error but i don't understand what policy i am missing...

```
eb ssh --setup Test-env
WARNING: You are about to setup SSH for environment "Test-env". If you continue, your existing instances will have to be **terminated** and new instances will be created. The environment will be temporarily unavailable.
To confirm, type the environment name: Test-env

Type a keypair name.
(Default is aws-eb):
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
C:\Users\steeve\.ssh\aws-eb already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)?
ERROR: NotAuthorizedError - Operation Denied. You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: CMrME2Q3zO8uzTOfmkZKzzZFtYI619QHlTlFKlnZYzbaLYS6bpdJqBg8yYOUj7WU7YJLqabtHgtp4U6kSMlNxvjpodMsdNirEP4aEr6yZL3Rum7MczDWdow9CdWJE_TOS3ULP2aFEa4Uas4rfwpCmEN1S7NRBIpGHrC_obKy3UgQygeXrcRJhxsvsfzTcEP7sLGd5y5KajPqoFso0HY2B0qSJ9XObX9bQrZ2wnADKaUuM1dyrJlJH_OAzNivJR1DeciqWkWjLJRHHWef7XhS3bpZJCXkM7ahpTwXZ5SOS5f1F-NU1dVxVzR9wYyp5XVhI0SM1FkEAFhK6T3TkkV6XqoYYKdwuyzQFoIX57LFpPLCxxAchM0xq2wenIlnlqW4Puu4g6oeo2SEd7E7HBd0Zk_QQx0dW1pZYZroLXMc37fZAYsEDOooeOq5I-qF-DIxMse_vMQnPMKpb5JW9g4vz_ZP0ToRirgWNdP0dd5rT7v2TbRnNFdFG3j3RoSe46qgaEt5GcFEjmwb-Kog_GE
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

i was missing EC2 and S3 permissions